# Cassandra partition problems

Tags: cassandra, timezone, bigdata, partition, wide-column-store

I am using cassandra db with billions of records, and I want to store data grouped by date. The problem is that I should query records with different timezones for users, but it stores data by GMT in partition keys. Is it correct to save different date fields for all timezones and create plenty of views? This would expand db to enormous size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to make modification of your application layer to perform normalization of the user's date into GMT & perform search, and then convert dates back into user's timezone after retrieval.

But be careful with using dates as partition key - this could create so-called "hot" partitions when all write traffic will hit the same partitions & won't be evenly distributed between nodes.

Comment: Thank you for reply. As I understand data is phisycally grouped by GMT in nodes, but I have to perform some aggregation functions for different timezones. Is it better to do this in application?

Comment: Most of aggregation is better to make in application, for example, in Spark. Cassandra has limited support for aggregations. In some cases you can write your own aggregation functions that will be executed inside Cassandra, but you need to realize what additional load you'll add to nodes. Like described here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateAggregate.html